# Adobe Illustrator is in Outline view, how can I change it back to regular viewing mode?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

As I was working on this document, it suddenly froze up as I was placing a picture on an artboard. So I closed everything and restarted my PC. When I opened that document again with AI, *everything* suddenly looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Looks like maybe your default view got switched to "Outline View"? Try Control-Y, that might solve the issue.

[image]